# How override style angular-bootstrap-datepicker - "ng-datepicker"

Tags: css

My problem with `ng-datepicker`, I think is very simple but i can't resolve it.

For example:

```
<input style="background: red;" type="text" data-ng-datepicker data-ng-options="datepickerOptions" data-ng-model="date">
```

Style is ignoring a understand this because in the broswer I got something like this:

```
<input style="background: red;" type="text" data-ng-datepicker data-ng-options="datepickerOptions" data-ng-model="date">
<input type="text"></input>
```

I tried:

```
ng-style, ng-class
```

without result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution by add

```
    <input id="datepicker" style="background: red;" type="text" data-ng-datepicker data-ng-options="datepickerOptions" data-ng-model="date">
```

No in custom css we can write some think like this:

```
    input #datepicker[type="text"]{color: red;}
```